# Consulta XQuery

Tags: xquery

Estoy realizando una tarea en ExistDB en la que debo realizar una serie de consultas XQuery, para ello tengo un archivo XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BatteryReport>
    <Client computerName="Test-PC" platformRole="Desktop" reportDate="2022-01-02">
        <InstalledBatteries>
            <Battery id="1" model="X00-X00" manufacturer="Asus" cycleCount="" designed="90.006" current="77.651" chemistry="LiON"/>
        </InstalledBatteries>
        <Reports>
            <Date startDate="2021-12-30">
                <Report startTime="12:38:59">
                    <State type="0"/> <!-- (0 = Active, 1 = Conected Standby, 2 = Suspended)    -->
                    <Source type="0"/> <!--  (0 = Battery, 1 = AC, -1 = Null)  -->  
                    <CapacityRemaining type="percentage">
                        46
                    </CapacityRemaining>
                </Report>
                <Report startTime="12:33:39">
                    <State type="0"/>  <!-- (0 = Active, 1 = Conected Standby, 2 = Suspended)    -->
                    <Source type="1"/> <!--  (0 = Battery, 1 = AC, -1 = Null)  -->  
                    <CapacityRemaining type="percentage">
                        45
                    </CapacityRemaining>
                </Report>
            </Date>
            <Date startDate="2021-12-31">
                <Report startTime="01:30:42">
                    <State type="0"/> <!-- (0 = Active, 1 = Conected Standby, 2 = Suspended)    -->
                    <Source type="0"/> <!--  (0 = Battery, 1 = AC, -1 = Null)  -->  
                    <CapacityRemaining type="percentage">
                        80
                    </CapacityRemaining>
                </Report>
                <Report startTime="02:33:00">
                    <State type="2"/>  <!-- (0 = Active, 1 = Conected Standby, 2 = Suspended)    -->
                    <Source type="-1"/> <!--  (0 = Battery, 1 = AC, -1 = Null)  -->  
                    <CapacityRemaining type="percentage">
                        45
                    </CapacityRemaining>
                </Report>
            </Date>
        </Reports>
        <BatteryLifeEstimates>
            <Period startDate="2021-11-22" endDate="2021-11-29">
                <AtFullCharge active="05:51:05" standby="22:12:51"/>
                <AtDesigned active="06:29:45" standby="24:39:39"/>
            </Period>
            <Period startDate="2021-11-29" endDate="2021-12-06">
                <AtFullCharge active="04:48:30" standby="24:19:59"/>
                <AtDesigned active="05:20:17" standby="27:00:48"/>
            </Period>
            <Period startDate="2021-12-06" endDate="2021-12-13">
                <AtFullCharge active="03:20:47" standby="622190:28:30"/>
                <AtDesigned active="03:42:54" standby="690720:45:16"/>
            </Period>
            <Period startDate="2021-12-13" endDate="2021-12-20">
                <AtFullCharge active="05:09:02" standby="35:05:26"/>
                <AtDesigned active="05:43:35" standby="39:00:47"/>
            </Period>
        </BatteryLifeEstimates>
    </Client>
</BatteryReport>
```

Y debo guardar mostrar en un HTML las ordenado por fechas los reportes, el caso es que al filtrar coger el dato de las fechas me da este error al obtener el atributo:

```
Saltó un error durante la recuperación de resultados: Failed to invoke method retrieveFirstChunk in class org.exist.xmlrpc.RpcConnection: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Error SENR0001: attribute 'startDate' has no parent element
```

Pero cuando hago la del padre me devuelve las fechas (de momento no ordeno porque no me devuelve las fechas)

Aquí os dejo también la consulta:

```
for $client in /BatteryReport/Client
    let $reportDate := $client/Reports/Date/@startDate
    return $reportDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Vale era una tontería, debía agregar el tipo de variable que debería devolver, esta es la consulta que funciona:

```
for $batteryReport in doc("batteryStatus.xml")//BatteryReport
    let $client := $batteryReport/Client
    let $battery := $client/InstalledBatteries/Battery
    let $reportDate := data($client/Reports/Date/@startDate)
return $reportDate
```